# Tensorflow 2 summaries with eager disabled

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since there are currently couple of issues with TF2 eager execution (e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30561), [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30533#issuecomment-518038676) or [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30952)), I am disabling it by calling `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`.

However, I would be very happy if I still could **log stuff to tensorboard**. The new version of file writer (which one gets by calling `tf.summary.create_file_writer()`) does not create any files if I disable eager execution. The old one (`tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter()`) does create a file but I am not able to write anything in. The `add_summary` function requires a summary protocol buffer (not a value) and I don't know how to create it without using the v1 session context.

Is there a way to write summaries in TF2 with disabled eager execution?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this question ?

Comment: @DollarAkshay Unfortunately not...